# PHP While loop adding blank row to repeating region

Tags: php, html

I have what is, to me, a confusing situation.
The following code is producing a blank row on the web page. I'm using the same code on different pages and they are working fine. The row count is set to display 5 rows but is showing 6 with the first one being devoid of any dynamic data.
I'm sure I've missed or overlooked something, can anyone shed any light on why this might be happening?
Cheers

```
    <?php
$counter = 0;
do {
$color = ($counter & 1)? "#FFF" : "#DEDEDE";
$counter++
?>
      <tr style="background: <?php print $color; ?>">
        <td ><a href="edit_workorder.php?jobID=<?php echo $row['jobID']; ?>" ><?php echo $row['wo_date']; ?></a></td>
        <td />
        <td ><?php echo $row['wcust_firstname']; ?> <?php echo $row['wcust_surname']; ?></td>
        <td ><?php echo $row['wcust_address']; ?> - <?php echo $row['wcust_suburb']; ?></td>
        <td ><?php echo $row['wo_equip']; ?></td>
        <td />
        <td ><?php echo $row['wo_problem']; ?></td>
        <td />
        <td ><?php echo $row['wtech_userlogin']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
} while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
 // close while loop
?>
```

Comment: Just change the do while to a while.

Comment: So there's a row before the header row?  The th tags?

Comment: Yes, the headers are in a separate row. The code I'm using is working fine on other pages in the site. I can't figure out where the problem is. I've compared the code from working pages to this one and there is no difference

Comment: Please try to improve the readability of your example by removing unrelated code (e.g. stuff like _align="left"_) to make a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Sorry for that, I've edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$row is not populated until you go through the loop the second time.

instead of

```
do{
 ...
}while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
```

do:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
...
}
```

Comment: That did it alright!! I'm still puzzled why the same code is 'working' on other pages, but I'll chalk it up to my lack of knowledge and experience with PHP. Thanks for the help on this. Good on ya, Cheers.

Comment: Depending on what the loop is doing the output can _look_ the same with either loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that with a [`do-while`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php) the expression in the while-clause is not executed in the first run. The consequence of this is that the `$row` array is not set and will thus not contain any values to print.

The code should be modified to this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){

}
```

---

Here's an example to illustrate how do-while works:

```
$i = 0;
do {
   echo $i;
}while($i++ < 3);
```

Outputs:

```
0
1
2
3
```

Whereas a standard while loop would output:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: Thank you, the correction has been made. I'm very new at all of it and fascinated with what can be achieved by using it, but I seem to muddle myself with my lack of knowledge and training on the subject. Thanks for the help.